# How to install Arduino IDE on Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino

How do you install the Arduino IDE on the Raspberry Pi running an ARM version of Ubuntu or Raspbian? There doesn't seem to be any [official ARM release](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases#00xx). Both distros have an "arduino" package in their standard repos, but it only includes an ancient 1.0 version that's missing a lot of features.

Comment: You planning to develop for arduino on your pi?

Comment: Arduino are explicitly open source, right?  So this should be possible.  If you just want it for loading code into the arduino you might investigate whether is a separate smaller piece of software you could use for that, which would simply things.

Answer (score 2):

The source code is available on the website you listed. You should be able to install the pre-requisite software, (gcc-avr, avrdude, avr-libc, and avr-evtd) and then compile the source code.

While entirely possible, this will probably take a long time. If you're using an RPi 2, make sure to take advantage of the multiple cores by using `make -j8` instead of `make`. Even so, compilation will take a long time; be prepared to wait.